# Getting the correct /usr/libXX folder for the current binary architecture

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, fhs

I am trying to find from my binary (which is supposed to be able to run on any distro), the canonical path to system libraries for a given distro / architecture.

Precisely, I am trying to load VST plug-ins which are shared objects which all distros store in folders such as `/usr/lib/vst/xxx.so`, `/usr/lib32/vst/xxx.so`, `/usr/lib64/vst/xxx.so`, etc.

Some distros just have `/usr/lib`, some have `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib64` be different folders with a different content entirely, some have `/usr/lib` symlinked to `/usr/lib64`... so I cannot just add all of them to my search path as that would sometimes give duplicates.

What tools can I use outside of a filesystem search which would be too slow, from a C++ program, to get *the* path to the folder that interests me, no matter which distro, past present or future, my users are running ?

Comment: _so I cannot just add all of them to my search path as that would sometimes give duplicates_ You _can_ add them all if you do `stat` on them and keep a copy of the `struct`. Skip if return is -1 (dir does not exist). Otherwise, compare `st_dev` and `st_ino` against all the previous entries. If they both match the candidate is a dup--skip it (i.e. it is a symlink/hardlink to one of the previous entries).

Comment: After that you may want to scan the directory looking for a `.so` (via `readdir`). Process the [ELF] header and reject the directory if the lib is the _wrong_ arch (e.g. 32 vs 64 bit or aarch64 vs x86_64, etc).